# Exclude values ending in a specific character in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I'm validating data from a table and I'm trying to exclude/ remove orders that end in the letter E from the column **ORDER_ID** , however, some of them will end in E1.
Also, some of the orders will contain a letter E at the beginning or middle of the order_id like**SDIE40000094113788**

Here example :
**SD40000093594337E** ;
**SD40000093171253E1**

I have tried the below code however that would remove all orders that contain **E **on the order_id

```
select ORDER_ID, case when  OC.order_id like any ('%E%') then 1 else 0 end as Exchange 
from shop_orders_production op 
where 1=1
and cast(op.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP as date) >= '2022-12-01'
and cast(op.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP as date) < '2023-01-01'
and Exchange = 0 ;
```

Ideally I just need to remove the ones with an E or E1 from my analysis and leave the rest.

Comment: Why not use OR? when order id LIKE '%E' OR order_id LIKE '%E1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'%E%'` expression selects all rows containing E. Instead use one filter with `'%E'` and another with `'%E1'`:

```
select ORDER_ID, case when OC.order_id like any ('%E') or OC.order_id like any ('%E1') then 1 else 0 end as Exchange 
from shop_orders_production op 
where 1=1
and cast(op.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP as date) >= '2022-12-01'
and cast(op.ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP as date) < '2023-01-01'
and Exchange = 0 ;
```